# How to dynamically update Meta tags (OG) using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, metadata, facebook-opengraph, meta

This is my first question here in the Stack community. I know it has been asked earlier, but I wanted to know how to do it specifically just using JS (I'm not a coder by education).

This is something what I am trying to do:

```js
var pageTitle = document.getElementsByTagName('h1');
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = pageTitle[0].innerHTML;
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Update meta tag dynamically</title>
<meta property="og:title" content="id=demo"/>
</head>
    <body>
        <h1>First header</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

I know the that's not how to use tags, just to show you what I want to do.

> PS: We can't run anything at the back-end, so it has to be in the
> code.

This is something else that I found, but it doesn't work either:

```
<meta name="description" content="Old">
<h1>New</h1>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var metaTitle = document.getElementsByTagName('h1');
    // Just replacing the value of the 'content' attribute will not work.
    $('meta[name=description]').remove();
    $('head').append( '<meta name="description" content"$metaTitle">' );
});
</script>
```

Comment: From your question it is not clear what you want to achieve. Please add some details on the _exact_ issue you're facing.

Comment: Okay so basically we have some documentation guides (around 1700 html pages), which we generate using a WYSIWYG editor (MadCap Flare). The editor only requires you to have one basic styled HTML page and it applies the code to rest of the pages when generating the guide. Currently, we have generic Meta tags for that basic page, thus all pages have same meta tags, which isn't useful. I want them to be updated dynamically using the contents of the page. The code demonstrated above intends to update title of the OG meta tag using H1.

Comment: did u try to $('head').append('<meta property="og:title" content="id=demo"/>')

Comment: Sorry, but didn't work.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Finally, cracked the code. Here it is for any future wanderers: https://github.com/idaljot/meta-tag-auto-update/blob/master/meta-tag.htm

Answer (score 0):

to dynamically change `og` properties

```html
    <head>
        <meta property="og:title" content="" />
        <meta property="og:url" content="" />
        <meta property="og:image" content="" />
        <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
        <meta property="og:description" content="" />
    </head>
```

```js
    const metas = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('meta'))
    const metaTitle = metas.find((m) => m.attributes[0].nodeValue === 'og:title')
    metaTitle.attributes[1].nodeValue = 'a title'
    const metaUrl = metas.find((m) => m.attributes[0].nodeValue === 'og:url')
    metaUrl.attributes[1].nodeValue = window.location.href
    const metaImage = metas.find((m) => m.attributes[0].nodeValue === 'og:image')
    metaImage.attributes[1].nodeValue = 'a image'
    const metaDescription = metas.find((m) => m.attributes[0].nodeValue === 'og:description')
    metaDescription.attributes[1].nodeValue = 'a description'
```